# Angular pipe with reactive formControlName of angular form array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

> Here i am using custom pipe to format the rate field.
> Which is read only field.
> Issue is value attribute not formating the rate field on page load.
> Which is working for another fields

```
<div formArrayName="rateList" *ngFor="let product of formData.controls; let i=index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <input formControlName="rate" readonly="readonly"
                        [value]="formData.controls[i].get('rate').value  | udpCurrency : false : this.translate.currentLang" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: you needn't use formControlName. Rememeber a FormGroup (formArray or FormControl) exist independly exist a input in .html or not).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer for this, but as a workaround you can use setTimeout at the time you are setting the value to the form array.

```
setTimeout(()=> {
  this.rateList.setValue(someRateArray)
} ,0)
```